# x86 assembly - printing a character given an ascii code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am new to assembly programming and am having trouble printing a character to the screen. Every time I execute my program I get a segmentation fault and I am not sure why.

```
.section .data
  A:
    .long  65  # ascii code for 'A'

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
 movl $1, %edx # length of character to print, 1
 movl  A, %ecx # what I want printed
 movl $1, %ebx # file descriptor for STDOUT
 movl $4, %eax # syscall number for sys_write

 int $0x80     # calls kernel

 movl $0, %ebx # return status
 movl $1, %eax # syscall number for sys_exit

 int $0x80     # calls kernel
```

**These are the commands I use to build**
(my file is named write.s)

```
as write.s -o write.o
ld write.o -o write
```

Is this not the correct way to print a character? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you assembling/linking this ? Note that it needs to be a 32 bit executable.

Comment: I am using the linux's standard assembler and linking. I will add the commands above because they are important. The `file` command lists my executable as a 32-bit ELF file.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check if the arguments are set up correctly?

Comment: For some reason I was expecting `movl` to load the address since A is an address. But `leal` did the job. Would you mind making this an answer and also could you point me to a debugger I can use for assembly? @NiklasB.

Comment: Did you read the http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/ ? Did you `strace` your program?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No I have been following a book called 'Programming from the Group Up', but I will definitely look at that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
movl A, %ecx
```

means: Copy the value at the address of the label A into `%ecx`. The correct instruction would be:

```
movl $A, %ecx
```

or

```
leal A, %ecx
```

You can use GDB for debugging in these cases (note that you have to assemble with the `-g` flag to get debug information):

```
$ as -g write.s -o write.o
$ ld write.o -o write
$ gdb write
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
   [.. snip ..]
(gdb) b test.s:13
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000c6: file test.s, line 13.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/niklas/tmp/asm/write 

Breakpoint 1, _start () at test.s:13
13   int $0x80     # calls kernel
(gdb) info registers ecx
ecx            0x41 65
```

As you see, `%ecx` has the integer value `65`, which is not what you want.

---

If you run `strace ./write`, it will decode the system call args and return value for you.  You'll see that `write()` just returns `-EFAULT` without doing anything else when you pass it a bad pointer.

Comment: Do you know how I could print a value that isn't in the data region? like if I just wanted to print the letter 'A' using its ascii code 65. Is there anyway to load immediate values?

Comment: @Hunter: You can put it on the stack: `pushl $0x41 # movl %esp, %ecx`. Note that you need to ensure that the string is null-terminated, too (which is the case here because of little-endianess). Of course you can also reserve space using `subl [size], %esp`.

Comment: I also finally got around to looking up how I can set breakpoints from within GDB :)

Comment: Not true that the "string" needs to be null-terminated - this ain't C!

Comment: @Frank: Very true, I'm too much used to coding against the libc in assembly :/